# Why do you think pentaho dashboard select filters get fixed at browser reloading?

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, kettle, pentaho-cde, dashboard-designer

I have a CDE dashboard at my Pentaho CE 8.2, however -after long loading time in browser-, the filter select for years says there is an error liading the component.
If I reload the page in the browser, it loads fine, and works great. Why fails first time page is openend?
Any ideas_?

Comment: might be issue with priority of loading component, give high priority and check.

Comment: Makes sense... however, I checked and has priority 1, so it loads before the others that have priority 5. Maybe something related though.

Comment: 5 is the highest priority.